# Explanation of pyplot objects and behaviour

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My question is kind of the 'too broad' category, but I already have been searching for hours, and my problem is still present.

I am making multiple (say 10) plots in a `for` cycle with my own Plotter function, and then saving them using `savefig()`. After that, I would like to make another plot and show it. No matter what I do, I still get 9 or 10 additional valid/empty plots.

```
for ...:
    pyplot = Plotter.plotStuff(data[i])
    pyplot.savefig(path)
    pyplot.clf()
pyplot.plot(new_data)
pyplot.show() # showing additional plots
```

My main question is: how could I "get a fresh start" and erase my previous plots? I tried `pyplot.clf()`, `pyplot.cla()` and `pyplot.hold(False)` with no luck.

Also, could someone please explain how the pyplot/figure/subplot dynamics work, when is it making a new plot, where is stored my data/previous plots? I had the "additional empty plot" problem before, but I reordered my commands until it worked, but I still have no clue why.

For example, I have `figure(), subplots_adjust(), plot(), xticks(), yticks()` commands (in this order). What should be the order and why?

Thank you very much, I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: In this line: `pyplot = Plotter.plotStuff(data[i])` you are assigning over the top of `pyplot`, so if you were expecting `pyplot` to contain the same functions as the `matplotlib.pyplot` module you will be disappointed.  I can't say much more without knowing what sort of object `Plotter.plotStuff` returns.

Comment: @ali_m The `plotStuff`function contains `pyplot.figure()`, ...,  `pyplot.yticks()` what I mentioned, and then `return pyplot`. Actually, when I put a `pyplot.close()` as @cmmnn mentioned in the answer below, it is working, and it's not a problem to overdefine the `pyplot` module with a modified `pyplot` module. Still renamed it just to be sure.

Comment: @ali_m For the pyplot behaviour: it looks similar to that of xlwings, and you select the figure with `pyplot.figure(number)`. Then you just call the pyplot functions like `pyplot.function()`, and it will make the effect on the selected figure. However, if I try to change the colour cycle, in the following way, it makes an empty figure 4, and puts the plots on figure 5: `pyplot.figure(4), ax = pyplot.subplots()[1], ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', ['y', 'r'])), pyplot.plot(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am by no means an expert, but from my understanding you use `figure()` to open create a new figure object. You can give an argument to this function to identify your different figures i.e. `figure(7)`, otherwise they are just enumerated I guess.

You can then put stuff into your figure object and afterwards use `savefig(), draw(), show()` on your figure.
You can also use `close()` to close the last figure you created or use an identifier here again.

So for your specific problem I think a `close()` at the end of the for loop should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! However, I am still not sure about everything, see my replies to @ali_m, maybe you can help.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help and I am suprised no matplotlib expert came around here and gave a better answer. I always click around the matplotlib thumbnail gallery until I find what I need and just thought a quick working fix may be needed until a matplotlib guru comes around and enlightens us with a deeper understanding.